# Solution for Xamarin Essentials StorageRead Permission Denied in Android 13 - DataPicker

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying select a photo by gallery using Data Picker of Xamarin Essentials, but when I click on Select Photo Button the app shows me the follow exception: "Xamarin.Essentials.PermissionException: 'StorageRead permission was not granted: Denied'"

This is my Android Manifest:

```xml
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.firebasepocxamarin" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
        <application android:label="FirebasePOCXamarin.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:icon="@drawable/login"></application>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    </manifest>
```

This is the function that use DataPicker:

```cs
 async void SelecionarFoto_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var result = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions
            {
                Title = "Choise the product photo"
            });

            var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();

            FotoProduto.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
        }
```

I'm using the Xamarin.Essentials(1.7.5) and Android 13.0 - API 33 emulator.
I tried with other emulator with API 30 and worked, but I want a solution for this exception in API 33 emulator.

Someone can help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: It looks to be same as [this issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/pull/2073) that was fixed in Xamarin.Essentials 1.7.5. Please use Solution / Manage nugets to double-check that you have 1.7.5 (or later). I've added a comment on that issue, linking to your question, to alert devs to the possibility that there is still an issue. WHAT YOU SHOULD DO: After double-checking that you have 1.7.5, Make a public github repo with just enough code to build and run, and show the issue. Run it to confirm it fails. Add a link to that repo, both in the issue I've linked, and at end of your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a remaining issue in the Xamarin.Essential 17.5. You can refer to this issue thread about [[Bug] Storage permissions Android 13 api 33](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/2041) for more information.

In addition, I tried the code on the xamarin and it still can not run. In the maui, it runs well.